# Evaluating a line integral given line segments of a curve

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

[image]

- We are asked to evaluate the given line integral where C consists of line segments from (0,0) to (9,1) and from (9,1) to (10,0)

First i parametrized the given line segments and divided the curve C as two curves

[image]

Now that i have defined the path in terms of a parameter, i will use the following equation to evaluate our line integral where x’(t) and y’(t) are the derivatives of the components of the parametrized line segments

[image]

First, we will integrate over the first line segment < 9t , t > from t=0 to t=1. x’(t)=9 and y’(t)=1

[image]

Now we integrate over our second line segment < 9+t , 1-t > from t=0 to t=1. here x’(t)=1 and y’(t)=-1

[image]

Finally we add up the results of both line integrals

[image]

However this is the wrong answer. Is the mistake algebraic or conceptual? Im not sure where i went wrong

Comment: Looks like you added instead of subtracting at the very end.

Comment: In the future, please format your mathematical expressions using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) instead of pasting in pictures of them. Your question is incomprehensible without those images, which makes it inaccessible to people who rely on screen readers. Moreover, images are neither searchable nor show up in summaries.

Comment: @amd wow i see it, thanks